# How to tell apollo-client to not apply normalization on specific fields?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

My GraphQL schema includes objects that have large arrays of data that are unique to this object and will not be found in other objects.

Exemple:

```
type Position {
  time: Integer
  latitude: Float
  longitude: Float
}

type ObjectInSpaceAndTime {
  name: String
  positions(start: Int, end: Int): [Position]
}
```

My understanding of normalization in GraphQL Client is that the response graph will be flattened, each instance of `Position` extracted in cache, a unique key created for it (from the path of the position, so something like `someobject.positions.42`). This is very CPU and memory intensive with thousands of values.

The cache will look like this:

```
{
  __ObjectInSpaceAndTime.someid: {name: 'xxx'},
  __ObjectInSpaceAndTime.someid.positions.0: {time: 1221121, latitude: 0, longitude: 0},
  __ObjectInSpaceAndTime.someid.positions.1: {time: 1221122, latitude: 0, longitude: 0},
  // ...
}
```

Instead, I would like to tell Apollo Client to not try to normalize this and just store the entire instance of `ObjectInSpaceAndTime` with its fields, and maybe the parameters passed to the fields so that a query with different attributes yields a cache-miss.
This will significantly reduce the work apollo has to do in memory when processing the reply. The array of data will be deserialized once from the response and can be used without apollo-client having to iterate over it.

```
{
  __ObjectInSpaceAndTime.someid: {name: 'xxx', 
       positions: [ {time: 1221121, latitude: 0, longitude: 0}, 
                    {time: 1221122, latitude:0, longitude: 0}, 
                    /* ... */ ], 
  // ...
}
```

Is this possible with Apollo Client? I cannot find a way to do this.

Suggestions on a better way to model this "graph" welcomed as well.

Comment: [apollo-cache-hermes](https://github.com/convoyinc/apollo-cache-hermes) looks like a great solution to my problem. The [Motivation](https://github.com/convoyinc/apollo-cache-hermes/blob/master/docs/Motivation.md) doc does a great job at explaining the issue I am running into.

Comment: "This is very CPU and memory intensive with thousands of values."
- Why not use a pagination strategy and store less values in memory at a time?

Comment: In my use-case I need all the data points to draw a graph of a variable or draw position history on a map. Server can pre-process to reduce the number of values but it's still going to be a large number of rows needed in memory to do the drawing.

Comment: we have the same problem, but for various reasons Hermes is not currently an option even though I've tested it and its performance is far better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I have found so far is to switch to another cache, namely [apollo-cache-hermes](https://github.com/convoyinc/apollo-cache-hermes/). Hermes will only store what they call "Entities", that is an object returned with an 'id' (I am simplifying but that is the default behavior).

I wrote a simple benchmarking tool, fetching an object with an array of 12k "points" associated to it. One of the attribute of the point is a GPS coordinate with keys for latitude and longitude.

With the default apollo-inmemory cache, I get:

```
1st query (not cached)
Network time: 2358ms
Received data navDataCount=12860 Timer=3013ms  Memory=82.41MB CacheEntries=25722
2nd query (cached)
Received data navDataCount=12860 Timer=19ms  Memory=86.26MB  CacheEntries=25722
```

Processing time in the cache: 655ms

With apollo-hermes:

```
1st query (not cached)
Network time: 2891ms
Received data navDataCount=12860 Timer=3079ms  Memory=23.36MB  CacheEntries=3
2nd query (cached)
Received data navDataCount=12860 Timer=51ms  Memory=22.37MB  CacheEntries=3
```

Processing time in the cache: 188ms

(I ran the tests multiple times and the processing times do not vary much).

Looks like a good solution to me, although I am surprised at how fast apollo-inmemory is able to respond on the second query. 655ms is not a bad time to process such a large number of objects and apollo-inmemory remains a very solid option.

Comment: Wow thanks, how does this not have more upvotes! I have tons of nested JSON objects like this and Apollo cache keeps normalizing them and then returning wrong ones when they don't have ID's... I'll try out Hermes though